# How to create an Array from a for loop and use it later

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

Ok so I am trying to create an Array with my data, because the way I was doing before was giving me some issues.

Code I am trying now

```
var frame=$('#avacweb_chat iframe');
 var uName=  $('.online-users li',frame.contents());
   var listedUsers = [];
  for(var i =0;i<uName.length;i++){
    var name = $(uName[i]).text();
     listedUsers = [name];
   }
    alert(listedUsers);
```

Code I have now is

```
 var membersList = $('.online-users li' , frame.contents()).text().replace("@","").trim();
 var memberUpdate = setInterval(function() {
 var newMember = $('.online-users li' , frame.contents()).text().replace("@","").trim();
if(membersList.length <= newMember.length) {
  var list= membersList.replace(newMember,"");
   alert(list);
 }
```

Then I have an alert, though it alerts like this

```
 `User1User2User3`
```

I want it to alert each time per say,

`User1`
`User2`
`User3`

So I figured if I made it an array it would be easier. though I am not positive on how I'd alert it like so after the array???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
listedUsers = [name];
```

to this:

```
listedUsers.push(name);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

If you want to later alert these names one-by-one:

```
for ( var j = 0; j < listedUsers.length; j++ ) {
    alert( listedUsers[ j ] );
}
```

Comment: Great. I knew I needed push but I did this listedUsers = [name].push(i); :D

How would I get the name I am trying to achieve in the second code? As well as later on alert each name. Say if the "log in" and thats what the var list is. I want `User1 logged in` `User2 Logged In` if you know what I'm saying